# Why is my system reading/writing to C:\windows\installer an absolute ton?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

The disk access light on the front of my machine is flashing ridiculously fast. Doing most anything (e.g. Loading Visual Studio) seems to take an extra long time. The resource monitor reports that my read/write usage is 10 MB/s - which seems like an awful lot of data to me.

It was read\writing to `C:\Windows\Installer\XXXXX.msi` on a few processes - 4-5 @ 1/MB/s each.

Why would my system be doing that?

Comment: 1 MB/sec isn't very much to be honest.  Have you ran a S.M.A.R.T test on the hdd?

Comment: Could be lots of things.  Virus?  Bad MSI?  Are they all the same MSI?  Can you kill the tasks?

Comment: All different .msi's I'm thinking that it's possible that it was some upgrades getting pushed out (it's a corporate machine)